# Allowing PPTP clients to access remote server's WAN connection

Tags: vpn, pptpd

Ok, I'm no VPN expert, but I'm experimenting with PPTPD on a little Debian 5 server.

When I log in to the server with a client, I can access the LAN resources, but I cannot figure out how to get the client to use the servers WAN (internet) connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For this to happen, the client's default gateway has to point at the VPN tunnnel, so that all traffic flows through it. There should be an option in the pptpd config file to set this.

WARNING: this can potentially go very wrong. Before you go down that road, check out what DNS service is available once the client has connected and whether there are any other firewall rules in place.